# adjacency matrix from real information network dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, dataset

This is the sample photo of the large dataset(csv format).I want to create an adjacency matrix from this dataset.I have tried lot of ways including trying cytoscape(a web tool http://www.cytoscape.org/) but the output matrix has errors.I am unable to find any good resources for it.

[image]

This is the code I have written:

def adjmat():

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('rawdata.csv', dtype='int', delimiter=',')
data = np.transpose(data)
row1 = data[0]
row2 = data[1]
n=0
n1=0
n2=0
row=0
col=0


n1=max(row1)
n2=max(row2)

if n1>n2:

    G=np.zeros((n1,n1))
    n=n1
else:
        G=np.zeros(n2,n2)
        n=n2




for i in range(0,len(row1)):

    row=row1[i]
    col=row2[i]
    G[row-1][col-1]=1

return G
```

X= adjmat()

Is there a better way than this?

Comment: First step would be to show us one of the ways you tried and didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
def adjmat():
    print 'begin creating adjen mat'
    data = sc.loadtxt('rawdata.csv', dtype='str', delimiter=',')
    data = sc.transpose(data)
    row1 = data[0].astype(int)
    row2 = data[1].astype(int)
    n=0
    n1=0
    n2=0


    n1=max(row1)
    n2=max(row2)

    if n1>n2:

        Amat=sc.zeros((n1,n1))
        n=n1


    else:
        Amat=sc.zeros((n2,n2))
        n=n2


    for i in range(0,len(row1)):

        row=row1[i]
        col=row2[i]

        Amat[row-1][col-1]=1


    return Amat
```

This is how I create the matrix.I have used it for graphs upto 30000 nodes.Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is what was needed.

Comment: How to use this for a million nodes?